# Pass arrays Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to ask what command I should use to pass an array of items from one class to the main activity, and then use this array of items to populate a list view

```
var result = webservice.salesOrderList(apikey, null);
```

I have to pass result in the main activity and then use it in a list view.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if your result of `var result = webservice.salesOrderList(apikey, null) ;` is an array of strings, you can define this result in your class for example like this:

```
public class DataSource
{
    public string[] result { get; set; }

    public DataSource()
    {
        result = webservice.salesOrderList(apikey, null);
    }
}
```

Then create your adapter to match the data source type string array for example:

```
public class MainAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    private string[] items;
    private Activity context;

    public MainAdapter(Activity context, string[] items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override string this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return items[position];
        }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return items.Length;
        }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position].ToString();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Finally use this adapter for your `ListView`:

```
public class MainActivity : ListActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var data = new DataSource();

        ListAdapter = new MainAdapter(this, data.result);
    }
}
```

This is the simplest method to create a `ListView`, you can of course customize your item style, or the `ListView`. For more information about creating a `ListView` in Xamarin.Android, you can refer to [ListViews and Adapters](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/).